# Can i use interface JdbcOperations for batch delete?

Tags: java, spring

I use batchUpdate for batch insert.

```
private static final String BATCH_INSERT = "INSERT INTO player_subscription (`player_id`,`channel_id`,`type_id`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

and etc.

can i use the same construction for delete?
and how should write query in this case?

EDIT: 
i want something like that but for Delete.

```
public void create(Collection<PlayerSubscription> playerSubscriptions, final Integer playerId)
    String query = "INSERT INTO player_subscription (`player_id`,`channel_id`,`type_id`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    final JdbcOperations jdbcOperations = getJdbcTemplate().getJdbcOperations();
    final ArrayList<PlayerSubscription> subscriptions = new ArrayList<>(playerSubscriptions);
    jdbcOperations.batchUpdate(query, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
            final PlayerSubscription playerSubscription = subscriptions.get(i);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, playerId);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, playerSubscription.getChannleId());
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, playerSubscription.getTypeId());
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return subscriptions.size();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please extend or re-phrase your question, it's confusing. You mention the `JdbcOperations` interface which is from Spring. However, your tag says `spring-data`. Furthermore, you only show the actual statement not how you use it.

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *guess* what you're looking for is [`JdbcOperations#batchUpdate(String, List<Object[]>)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.List-).

Untested example:

```
// deletes users with ID 1, 2
List<Object[]> ids = new ArrayList<>();
ids.add(new Object[]{1L}); // user ID 1
ids.add(new Object[]{2L}); // user ID 2
jdbcOperations.batchUpdate("delete from user where id = ?", ids);

// deletes users 'Paul Muller' and 'Jack Jones'
List<Object[]> users = new ArrayList<>();
users.add(new Object[]{"Paul", "Muller"});
users.add(new Object[]{"Jack", "Jones"});
jdbcOperations.batchUpdate("delete from user where firstname = ? and lastname = ?", users);
```

Comment: Yes, i really want to do something like that.
But i don't understand how should look query for three param.

Comment: I don't understand your question but I added a second example which _might_ be closer to what you're after.